# AWS Build Failing after making no significant code changes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, lambda

I recently added a few NPM packages and import lines to my react app to support IE11 compatibility. Prior to adding these changes, there was no error deploying to AWS, but afterwards, the build fails. This is strange because none of the changes seemingly could break the build, as they are very small. I'm getting this log error when deploying:

```
[Container] 2019/07/24 17:19:36 Running command export RELEASE=$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION 

[Container] 2019/07/24 17:19:36 Running command npx serverless deploy --stage=$STAGE 
Serverless: Trying to create certificate for escal.dev.app.esports.one in us-east-1 ... 
Serverless: Certificate for escal.dev.app.esports.one in us-east-1 already exists with arn "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:(...)". Skipping ... 
Serverless: 'escal.dev.app.esports.one' was created/updated. New domains may take up to 40 minutes to be initialized. 

  Error -------------------------------------------------- 

  Command failed: # Do not create a certificate for "prod" or "prod-admin" stages 
( (test "dev" = "prod" || test "dev" = "prod-admin") || sls create-cert --stage=dev) && 
sls create_domain --stage=dev && 
# Run build script with env vars defined in this config 
sls client build -p npm -c "run build" --stage=dev >/dev/null 


     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable. 

  Get Support -------------------------------------------- 
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com 
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues 
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com 

  Your Environment Information ----------------------------- 
     OS:                     linux 
     Node Version:           8.11.0 
     Serverless Version:     1.32.0 


[Container] 2019/07/24 17:20:39 Command did not exit successfully npx serverless deploy --stage=$STAGE exit status 1 
[Container] 2019/07/24 17:20:39 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED 
[Container] 2019/07/24 17:20:39 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npx serverless deploy --stage=$STAGE. Reason: exit status 1 
[Container] 2019/07/24 17:20:39 Entering phase POST_BUILD 
[Container] 2019/07/24 17:20:39 Uploading S3 cache... 
[Container] 2019/07/24 17:22:05 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
```

Comment: How many times have you deployed previously?

Comment: @AndyGaskell Upwards of 25

Comment: And the value of `$STAGE` hasn't changed?

Comment: @AndyGaskell Nope

Comment: Did you update npm packages when you installed the new packages, specifically `serverless-certificate-creator` or `serverless-domain-manager`?

Comment: @AndyGaskell I ran npm update, do I have to go in and update those individually?

Comment: Depending on how your [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) is setup you may have updated some dependencies that you didn't mean to (like your serverless plugins) and those dependencies broke. You'll want to do a diff on your old package-lock and your new one.

Comment: @AndyGaskell The following are the changes in package.lock from the diff:
https://puu.sh/DYSnX/b93de677d3.png 
https://puu.sh/DYSpy/00f4158370.png
https://puu.sh/DYSqb/f4088ca541.png
https://puu.sh/DYSqB/7e4fd0bd4e.png

Comment: Hey, what solved your problem?